# Get an array of size as big as 10^12 in C

Tags: c, arrays, size

I have to find prime numbers between two given numbers `a` and `b`, both of them ranging between `1` and `10^12`. To do this, I am using a Sieve of Eratosthenes. How can I get such a big array? Exceeding the size `10^6` gives an error.

Comment: you need 1TB just for that array, are you sure you need `10^12` array?

Comment: Do you need to "find" prime numbers or "find and save" prime numbers?

Comment: Download moar RAM, (lots moar RAM), and get a 64 bit OS.

Comment: For a sieve you only need one bit per number, and 10^12 bits is only 120 MB, well within the capacity of an ordinary PC.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: You can get away with one bit for every two numbers if you only search the odd numbers and treat the number 2 as a special case. That halves the amount of storage required.

Answer (score 1):

> to find prime numbers between two given numbers a and b, ...  between 1 and 10^12. ... using a Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Algorithm:

To find determine if a number is a prime, the classic approach is to attempt division of all primes 2 ... sqrt(n).

So create a *Sieve of Eratosthenes*: byte/bit wise flags in the range [0 ... 10^6].

Then test each value `[a ...b]` against the primes in the array.

So in the end only an array of 1,000,000 is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please quote the exact error. If you do have enough memory, the code should compile just fine.

But chances are, you do not have the terabytes of memory this would need. So you should probably think about a better algorithm that trades some memory space for some execution time.

Answer (score 0):

As said here, you need a lot of RAM (and, of course 64-bit OS) for that kind of allocation.
You can resort to a different algorithm, like this one for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

bool isPrime(unsigned long long n) {
    if (n == 2 || n == 3)
        return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
        return false;
    unsigned long long check = (n + (n % 3)) / 3;
    while (check>3) {
        if (n % check == 0)
            return false;
        check-=2;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (unsigned long long l = 2; l < ULLONG_MAX; l++)
    {
        if (isPrime(l))
            printf("%d, ", l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get upto 10^8 by dynamically allocating memory by pointer,like:
    `int *p=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*100000000)`
code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int *p=malloc(sizeof(int)*100000000);
    p[5]=147;
    printf("%d\n",p[5]);
}
```

Sieve of Eratosthenes require only sqrt(input array element) sized array.For example Sieve of Eratosthenes needs only a[10] for 100 numbers. Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation in C++ below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
void same(int);
void creat(int);
vector< int>v;
int main()
{
    int a,b,c,i,root,temp;
    cin>>a;
    while(a--)
    {
        cin>>b>>c;
        if(b==c)
        {
            same(b);
            continue;
        }
        temp=b;

        if(b%2==0 )
        {
            if(b==2) {b=3;}
            else
                ++b;
        }

        if (b==1)
        {
            b=3;
        }

        if(temp==2||temp==1||temp==0)
        {
            cout<<2<<endl;
        }
        creat((int)sqrt(c));
        for(i=b; i<=c; i+=2)
        {
            int flag=1;
            root=(int)sqrt(i);
            for(auto j=v.begin();*j<=root && j!=v.end(); ++j)
            {
                if(i%(*j)==0)
                {
                    flag=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag)
            {

                cout<<i<<endl;

            }
        }

        cout<<endl;
        v.clear();

    }
    return 0;
}
void same(int n)
{
    if(n==1) return ;
    int rot=(int)sqrt(n);
    for(int i=3; i<=rot; i+=2)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            return ;
        }
    }
    cout<<n<<endl;
}

void creat(int n)
{

    const int h=n/2;
    int a[h+1],i,j;
    for( i=0; i<=h; i++)
    {
        a[i]=0;
    }

    int r=(int)sqrt(n);
    for(i=3; i<=r; i+=2)
    {
        if(a[i/2]==0)
        {
            for(j=i*i; j<=n; j+=2*i)
            {
                a[j/2]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=3; i<=n; i+=2)
    {
        if(a[i/2]==0)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
```

`Input:`

`Number of test case
 lower range
 upper range`

`1
1
100`

`Output:`
`Prime numbers from 1 to 100`